# ASP.NET MVC3 ActionFilterAttribute Priority/Selection - Bizarre?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, actionfilterattribute

I just noticed a strange behavior with ActionFilterAttribute priority in MVC3.  It turns out that if both a Controller and an Action are decorated with the same ActionFilterAttribute with AllowMultiple = false (the default), then the one with the HIGHER Order value is selected.  In the case of a tie (i.e. both Order values are the same), then the filter on the Action is selected.  I had always thought that the filter on the Action would always be selected (if one is present), regardless of the Order value. Examples:

**Filter on Action is selected:**

```
[MyActionFilter(Name = "Controller")] // same as Order = -1
public class HomeController : Controller {

    [MyActionFilter(Name = "Action")] // same as Order = -1
    public ActionResult Index() {
        return Content("Hello");
    }

}
```

**Filter on Controller is selected:**

```
   [MyActionFilter(Name = "Controller", Order = 1)]
    public class HomeController : Controller {

        [MyActionFilter(Name = "Action")] // same as Order = -1
        public ActionResult Index() {
            return Content("Hello");
        }

    }
```

**Filter on Action is selected:**

```
[MyActionFilter(Name = "Controller", Order = 1)]
public class HomeController : Controller {

    [MyActionFilter(Name = "Action", Order = 1)]
    public ActionResult Index() {
        return Content("Hello");
    }

}
```

**Filter on Controller is selected:**

```
[MyActionFilter(Name = "Controller", Order = 20)]
public class HomeController : Controller {

    [MyActionFilter(Name = "Action", Order = 1)]
    public ActionResult Index() {
        return Content("Hello");
    }

}
```

Is this a bug or by design? I've been using MVC since version 1 and never noticed this filter selection priority.  Has it always been this way?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you set `AllowMultiple = false` and have the same action filter on both the controller and the action the one on the controller is **never** executed. If you set `AllowMultiple=true` it is the filter on the controller that gets executed first assuming same order.

The thing that changed in ASP.NET MVC 3 is the following:

> In previous versions of ASP.NET MVC,
>   action filters are create per request
>   except in a few cases. This behavior
>   was never a guaranteed behavior but
>   merely an implementation detail and
>   the contract for filters was to
>   consider them stateless. In ASP.NET
>   MVC 3, filters are cached more
>   aggressively. Therefore, any custom
>   action filters which improperly store
>   instance state might be broken.

So to ensure that you are properly testing this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, AllowMultiple = true)]
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
Put a breakpoint here and inspect the value of the Name property ====>
        var name = Name;
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Darin, but I'm seeing a different result than what you state. I'm setting AllowMultiple = false.  If on the attribute of the Controller, I set Order = 1 and on the action with the same attribute, I don't set Order, then the attribute on the Controller is executed.  I'm checking this by doing System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Name) in the OnActionExecuting override of the Attribute.  Can you please try running your example with a higher Order value on the attribute of the Controller and confirm that the attribute on your Controller is indeed never run?  Thanks.